# Read MySQL password from seperate file

Tags: php, security, github

I am trying to obfuscate a MySQL password within my PHP source code, because it is displayed publicly on Github. Here is what I did:

```
$pword = file_get_contents('../.brown_bag');
$obj->password = $pword;
```

This doesn't work, I get an access denied error. The file, `.brown_bag`, contains only one line with a string of only letters. I'm pretty sure `file_get_contents()` is not returning the data that I expected. I was trying to write concise, simple code and so have avoided the whole `fopen` rigmarole.  Why doesn't this work, and is there a better way?

Comment: Are you sure that the file you're trying to open is where you think it is? Try it with an absolute path, and see if that works?

Comment: Just leave the password empty when pushing it to github.

Comment: andrewsi yes I can echo the password from that file.

Comment: Louis I don't want to have remove the password everytime I make a commit.

Comment: An alternative would be to just add a example config file to github and not the real one, for example just add `config.php.example` with empty or example values.

Comment: @shakabra I'm expecting you kept password in config file. If not, put it in config file. If yes, First thing, why will you commit config file frequently? it needs to be done when you introduce new property in config file, which should happen occasionally. Editing it once a while should not be a problem. At-least this is the standard practice that most developers follow. Again you will not commit files from your server but from dev box. Does it really matter if you commit local db password by mistake?

Comment: @KapilSharma I am trying to keep "site specific config" separate from "common site config". MySQL passwords seem like "site specific" to me. BTW I'm making a simple CMS, please spare me the reinventing the wheel speech. The live site code is hosted on github. As such every time I commit I would have to remove the password. But you have given me reason to rethink this approach. However I still don't understand why file_get_contents() is not providing the proper password to the DB.

Comment: Sorry posted early. I am having issues with my internet, I am travelling at the moment, and github is down. But when I get the chance I will try some of your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Nobody answered why it doesn't work. I still don't know. The path was _definitely_ correct. I decided to go with solution of using an example file with empty values and removing the real file from my repo. @jeroen please provide an answer so I can vote for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to why it does not work, have you tried echoing out the value read from the file? It might be something as simple as a space or new-line, so you could try:

```
$obj->password = trim($pword);
```

An alternative would be to just add a example config file to github and not the real one, for example just add `config.php.example` with empty or example values.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't try the trim() idea. I just used the example config.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. The only possible issue is, file path is not correct. To make that sure, give absolute path of the file like (C:\a\b\c.brown_bag or /home/user/.brownbag)

If above work, you will be sure its path issue. If not, come with exact error, what it report by some debugging.

On better way: Password should always go in config file. Config file is one that is not committed on git until there is some change. Config file should be edited locally to get the password. However I assume you are using .brown_bag as config file. Still I'll suggest some better naming conventions. Better, make config file as php file and define your password as array or constant or simply define it in config file.

Comment: This is the full warning:                                      `code`
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'wurkwith_admin'@'espressoguild.com' (using password: YES) in /home/shakabra/noel.wurkwith.us/admin/inc/common.php on line 163
Could not connect. Access denied for user 'wurkwith_admin'@'espressoguild.com' (using password: YES)